# What is the part of speech/function of "to ten?"

Tags: parts-of-speech

What is the part of speech/function of "to ten" of sentence below?

> He narrows list of candidates for vacant seats to ten.

Comment: Prepositional phrase

Answer (score 1):

It is a prepositional phrase. "To" is a preposition, and the noun "ten" is its object.

However, this sentence has an error: the phrase "list of candidates for vacant seats" lacks a determiner.

Comment: I'd say that the cardinal numerals belong to the category (part of speech) 'determinative', and their function is that of 'determiner'. In the example given, "ten" determines the noun "candidates", i.e. "ten candidates".